# Is there a performance hit in using the 'var' keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# ‘var’ vs specific type performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/c-var-vs-specific-type-performance)

I use the 'var' keyword extensively. A colleague told me there was a performance hit in using it, but couldnt back up his comment. Does anyone know of such a performance hit?

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/c-var-vs-specific-type-performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone asked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/c-var-vs-specific-type-performance) on here already. In short, no, the IL code generated is the same. Therefore, no perf hit. If you ever wonder how one way of doing something differs from another, just write a sample and then use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to analyze the differences.

Comment: then the question should be closed as duplicate, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I searched SO, but couldnt find anything about this.

Answer (score 5):

No, `var` is just syntactical sugar. It doesn't actually get compiled into MSIL. Give a try compiling some code with the var keyword and without, then open the assembly in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to see for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a compile-time feature, there could conceivably be slower compilation times, but not slower run-times.

Comment: Yes. It can add many nanoseconds to your build.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is called type inference.  Compiler will infer the correct type at compile time and the msil generated will contain the correct type

Answer (score 1):

Does he mean at compile time or at runtime?

At runtime, it is not possible to have a performance hit.  The `var` keyword is handled entirely by the compiler, and it is completley impossible to tell from the IL whether the `var` keyword was used.  Your friend might be thinking of C# 4's new `dynamic` keyword, which does have a performance impact.

At compile time, there might be a tiny performance impact, but it's nothing to worry about.