# using var has any side effects?

Tags: c#, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# 'var' vs specific type performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/c-var-vs-specific-type-performance)

Are there any performance costs (in terms of type conversion, etc.) if I write the line

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
```

as

```
var c = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
```

Comment: No type conversion occurs. `var` is syntactic sugar, the compiler infers the correct type.

Comment: Come on, this has been asked a dozen times on SO alone (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/c-var-vs-specific-type-performance and its `linked` section for some). Is this kind of thing really that hard to google or infer from the easily-googleable descriptions of the feature?

Comment: There are also times when there is no static type, creating or projecting into anonymous types for instance. You have to use var as the type then.

Comment: And can people please find other excuses to ask questions than "performance costs"?

Comment: @delnan: sorry, I guess i am too lazy today :)

Comment: The difference should be explained by now. Note that using `var` instead of types makes your code much more refactoring friendly, too :)

Comment: @BoltClock: Not sure what you mean by finding excuses. I just came across this code that was using var and start thinking about any potential side effects this may have. I understand that this question may been asked before but you just don't answer if you don't like it; Is it too big a deal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The compiled IL is identical.

The only potential side effect is in the case of inheritance, if you're variable definition is a base class, and you instantiate a subclass.  If you do:

```
 BaseClass item = new DerivedClass();
```

This will potentially act differently than:

```
 var item = new DerivedClass();
```

This is because the second compiles to:

```
 DerivedClass item = new DerivedClass();
```

In most cases, it should behave identically (due to the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).  However, if `DerivedClass` uses [method hiding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) it is possible to have a change in behavior.

Comment: so then why any develoepr should use "var" when using "SqlConnection" make code more readable (IMHO)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c

Comment: @Silverlight Student: Most people feel that the first makes the code more readable - especially in the case of method chains used in features like LINQ.  It also allows for anonymous types to be used.

Comment: Because he thinks the redundancy makes it less readable. But there are existing questions on this. It comes down to a matter of style, and those a personal preference. And there are some scenarios (anonymous types) where `var` is necessary since you can't name the type explicitly.

Comment: @Silverlight Student: It's a matter of taste--but it can shorten up a line of code considerably if the type name is long (especially when using generics) and makes a line more readable in certain cases by not repeating the type name. It also comes in handy when writing code in books or forums to shorten up otherwise lenghy lines of code so that the reader can concentrate on the relevant part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The compiler knows at compile time what `var` should be (the return of `new SqlConnection` is, in fact, `SqlConnection`.  When the compiler knows the type of the right hand side, you can use `var`.

This has no runtime performance implications

Answer (score 0):

I believe var is processed at compile time, so it is simply a shortcut for writing the code. This means that the compiled version is identical.