# Using list<type> or var keyword difference

Tags: c#, resharper, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# ‘var’ vs specific type performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/c-sharp-var-vs-specific-type-performance)

When I write below code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

resharper wants to convert it to

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

Why? What is the difference? 
Is it more understandable? I think not.

Using `var` has more than the other cost on RAM. Isn't it?

Comment: var gets compiled into `List<string>` so it does not impose any runtime penalty.

Comment: There is no difference. They are both compiled to the same thing. I personally find `var` more readable, but that's it.

Comment: You don't have to follow the suggestion, you can set it to show as an hint.

Comment: It's exactly the same. var is just "syntacti sugar" for the explicit type of your variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the same. `var` is implicitly typed.

If you hover over the keyword `var` in Visual Studio, it will show you the type of your object - in this case `List<string>`. The use of `var` is only to clean up code - you already know you're creating an object of type `List<string>`, so some people think it is redundant to type:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

There is no performance difference, as the compiler already knows what type the object is. Using var personal preference mostly - you can use it if you want to and there is no performance hit.

Eric Lippert has a great blog post about `var` [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx).

I think you're confusing `var` and `dynamic`, which are two totally different things. The `dynamic` type is a type that allows you to assign values of different types to it at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = new List<int>();
```

The compiler uses the return type of the right hand to determine the type of list. In this case `List<string>`. So no difference. Just shorter way to initialize your variable.

Note that you can't use var when declaring fields.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all. The only thing that is worth noting is that the `var` keyword does NOT create a dynamic object. It's still a strongly typed object, but the compiler can infer the the type from the right operand of the variable declaration statement.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind this is that it's easier to refactor if you use 'var'. For instance, if you returning type "Foo" from a method and then convert it to return an interface instead, you would not have to change any of your client code - the new type would be inferred and used correctly.