# Which is better, "var array = ..." or "string[] array = ..."?

Tags: c#

Which of the following execute faster and use the least amount of memory:

```
var array = new string[5];
```

or

```
string[] array = new string[5];
```

Also, what are the differences between these statements?

Comment: no, final compilation, will give same result

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/will-using-var-affect-performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler sees them as the same thing. Here's some IL from LINQPad to show that:

```
var array = new string[5];
```

**IL:**

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0002:  newarr      System.String
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // array
```

and for `string[] array = new string[5];`

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0002:  newarr      System.String
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // array
```

In the first example, the `var` keyword lets the compiler infer the type of `array`. The compiler sees it as an array of `string`s so the resulting IL code for both examples are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

It will be compiled to *exactly* same IL code. Type of `array` variable will be inferred from usage, and compiler will generate variable of `string[]` type in first case.

Just read what MSDN tells about [var (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method
>   scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local
>   variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type
>   yourself, but the compiler determines the type. The following two
>   declarations of i are functionally equivalent:
>
> var i = 10; // implicitly typed
>
> int i = 10; //explicitly typed

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.First one is [implicit type definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) and second is explicit type definition.There is nothing about  memory efficiency here