# Performance impact of using var type

Tags: c#

I have noted in c# that using var improves your performance, especially when declaring variables of a specific class. I have done multiple bench marks and have got the same result every time. I have also read similar questions on this site and others. but no one has actually commented on this. 
Can anyone please confirm or refute this. 
 I have a 
class for image data, clsImageData 
and collection clsImageDataCollection. 
a function in collection class is SetCaseLowerCase(). 
Code is

```
private void SetCaseLowerCase()
{ 
   foreach (var item in this) 
   { 
      item.DestinationImageName = item.DestinationImageName.ToLower(); 
   } 
}
```

Now if I use clsImageData instead of var, it performs slower, I have checked it with 100000 iterations. but results is always the same. also with other examples too. 
Thanks

Edited
I have tested this simple code and got 7/10 times better performance using var. Please tell me what am I doing wrong, I am using VS 2017, debug mode for any CPU, my processor is quad core. Thanks

```
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                var xyz = "test";
            }
            StopClock(sw, "Example var - ");
            sw.Start();
            for(int i = 0; i<10000000; i++)
            {
                string xyx2 = "test";
            }
            StopClock(sw, "Example type - ");
```

Comment: There is no performance impact or otherwise. Whoever told you that is quite frankly wrong

Comment: I think this link could help you more  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/will-using-var-affect-performance

Comment: It is only syntactic sugar. Variables defined with `var` are still strongly-typed and is determined at compile time. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var

Comment: This should be marked as a duplicate

Comment: You could add that information to your question, its impossible to read in a comment

Comment: ok, this is my first time using the platform

Answer (score 1):

`var` is compiled in a way, that makes the use of it equals to just declaring the variable/  type (except in cases it cant be done somehow else but using `var` ex: anonymous types). that means there are no performance changes at all. read more about var at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var

here is a demonstration, type the following code:

```
var list = new List<int>();
```

note that when you hover above `list` your IDE says:

> `(local variable) List<int> list`

the reason for that is that `var` is converted to the declared type, meaning that var is actually cosmetic and its use can not impact any performance.